# How do I get a sha256 hash that is only alphanumeric?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, hash, cryptography, sha256

`return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('base64');`

This code currently produces a hash that has symbols.  I would like the hash to be alphanumeric.

I tried to `digest('base36')`, but that is not an option in node.js

Comment: Did you search before asking? There's obviously no built-in functionality. The requirement will require you to write base36 implementation. Or you can save some time by picking up existing one. Like https://www.npmjs.com/package/hash36

Comment: Hex is alphanumeric...doesn’t use all the alpha values, but it meets the definition

Comment: If you want a base62 encoder you'll probably need to write your own.